# Measure on surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: analysis, geometry, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, surfaces

I am interested in the following three surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$:

$$S_1=\{(x,y,x+y+x^3+\sqrt{y}): x \in [0,x_0], y\in [0,y_0]\},$$

$$S_2=\{(x,y,x+y+x^2 +y^2+1): x \in [0,x_0], y\in [0,y_0]\},$$

$$S_3=\{(x,y,x+y+x^4 +y^3): x \in [0,x_0], y\in [0,y_0]\}$$
for some $x_0, y_0>0$.

I wonder if there is a natural extension of the notion of Lebesgue measure (in $\mathbb{R}^n$) on these surfaces and a natural notion of open sets on these surfaces such that something like the Lebesgue density theorem would hold using these two extended notions?

Comment: Are you familiar with the treatment of *arc length* as a measure for curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Unfortunately not but I would like to read about it. Can it a basis for defining a measure?

Comment: The [arc length of a rectifiable curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length) is a topic in first-year calculus, so usually presented in connection with Riemann integration, but it does define a "natural" measure on smooth curves.  It can be adapted to give a measure on surfaces of the functional form in your examples.  More generally one can treat these surfaces as *manifolds-with-boundaries* and ask about measures on manifolds, but I suspect you will get good calculations using the calculus notions.

Comment: Thank you @hardmath ! I'll check out the arc length topic. A more general  treatment as manifolds-with-boundaries sounds interesting as well. Are there any standard references for this?

Comment: For the general $n$-dimensional study, some good links are collected [here, Geometric measure theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_measure_theory).  For the specific topic [Surface area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_area) the Wikipedia article points out some of the additional complications over the definition of arc length.

Comment: A classroom note on one such complication, [Schwarz's Paradox](http://fredrickey.info/hm/CalcNotes/schwarz-paradox.pdf), gives insight into the care with which limits of approximating polyhedral areas must be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the area formula from multivariable calculus. In your case each of the three surfaces $S_1,S_2,S_3$ is the graph of a function $z=f(x,y)$ defined for all $(x,y)$ in some (measurable) subset $D$ of the plane. Any (measurable) subset of the surface can be written in the form $f(A)$ for some (measurable) subset $A \subset D$. Furthermore, $f(A)$ is an open subset of the surface if and only if $A$ is an open subset of $D$. The area formula gives us
$$Area(f(A)) = \int\!\!\int_A \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2 + 1} \,\,\,\, dx \, dy
$$
and that's what you can use as Lebesgue measure on the surface. The Lebesgue density theorem will hold for this measure.

Comment: Thank you @Lee Mosher . I guess I would then treat $f(B((x_0,y_0),r))$ as "open balls" on the surface. What properties of the Lebesgue measure would this measure $Area(f(A))$ have? Would it e.g. have translation invariance?

Comment: "Translation invariance" only makes sense under the action of some translation group. But I cannot see any translation group that acts in the case of your three surfaces.

Comment: There is a slight infelicity in using $f(x,y)$ to represent both the dependent coordinate $z$ associated to $(x,y) \in A$ and the (three-dimensional) point on the surface, more properly designated $(x,y,f(x,y))$.

Comment: What metric are you using? The usual surface area form would be $dS=\sqrt{1+f_{x}^{2}+f_{y}^{2}}\;dx\wedge dy$

Comment: Oops, that was sloppy. Thanks @rych.